# Graphdiff is removing entities

Tags: entity-framework, graphdiff

I have the following entities:

```
public class Profile
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IList<Functionality> Functionalities { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Functionality
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

In my service method, when I try the following, it removes from the database the Functionality objects that are not in Profile's Functionalities list:

```
(...)
var databaseFunctionalities = this
                             .Repository
                             .GetByIds<Functionality>(profile
                                                     .Functionalities
                                                     .ToIdList());
profile.Functionalities.Clear();
profile.Functionalities.AddRange(databaseFunctionalities);

((BaseRepository)this.Repository)
.UpdateGraph(profile,map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.Functionalities));
this.Repository.SaveChanges();  
(...)
```

Any ideas about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution after reading andypelzer's explanation about differences between Associated and Owned in this post:

https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff/issues/43

So I changed

```
((BaseRepository)this.Repository)
    .UpdateGraph(profile,map => map.OwnedCollection(p => p.Functionalities));
this.Repository.SaveChanges();
```

to

```
((BaseRepository)this.Repository)
    .UpdateGraph(profile,map => map.AssociatedCollection(p => p.Functionalities));
this.Repository.SaveChanges();
```

and works like a charm!